# How to perform back extrapolation for each subject in R

Tags: r

I have such dataset

```
data_long=structure(list(id_manag = structure(c(50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L), levels = c("Aldar Raldin", "Alek P", "Alex K", "Alice G.", 
"Amy G", "Ana M", "Andy", "Anton C", "Danny F", "Dimitris K", 
"Dmitrii Adsterra", "Egor M", "Eliza B", "Elizabeth D", "Emma M", 
"Evgeny Vlasov", "Greg E", "Ian K", "Jacob Adsterra", "James D", 
"Jeff S", "Jena M", "John M", "Kate C", "Kos", "Luke M", "Lyle F", 
"Mandy Miles", "Marie N", "Marina S", "MB_Adsterra", "Miles B", 
"Nadia K", "Nataly R", "Nickie D", "Paul J", "Roman K", "Ronnie T", 
"Saul B", "Sonya Adsterra", "Tanya S", "Ted B", "Trevor Adsterra", 
"Tsugur T", "Ulia L", "Vincent", "Violet W", "Xander D", "Zach K", 
"Zoya S"), class = "factor"), month = structure(c(19052, 19083, 
19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236, 19266, 19297, 19327, 19358, 
19389, 19417, 19448, 19478, 19509, 19539, 19570, 19601, 19631, 
19662, 19692, 19723, 19052, 19083, 19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 
19236, 19266, 19297, 19327, 19358, 19389, 19417, 19448, 19478, 
19509, 19539, 19570, 19601, 19631, 19662, 19692, 19723, 19052, 
19083, 19113, 19144), class = "Date"), seconds = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
117L, 200L, 181L, 177L, 207L, 323L, 210L, 361L, 490L, 415L, 773L, 
372L, 275L, 322L, 391L, 335L, 294L, 253L, 269L, 278L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 211L, 427L, 333L, 102L, 161L, 280L, 412L, 1058L, 
642L, 558L, 142L, 168L, 173L, 250L, 225L, 168L, 261L, 251L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 210L), date_start = structure(c(18993, 18993, 18993, 
18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 18993, 
18993, 18993), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data presents these columns `id_manag`(name of manager), the `dates`(month) and the `seconds` of the negotiation time. (metric variable).

Each `id_manag` begins his work at any time after the first of March 2022. For example, some got a job in March 2022, someone in February 2023 and so on.
I need to extrapolate the data by `seconds` from the start date of its work, to 2022-01-01, that is, like a forecast (extrapolation) back for each `id_manag` separately.

For example

```
   id_manag      month seconds date_start
1    Zoya S 2022-03-01       0 2022-01-01
2    Zoya S 2022-04-01       0 2022-01-01
3    Zoya S 2022-05-01       0 2022-01-01
4    Zoya S 2022-06-01     117 2022-01-01
5    Zoya S 2022-07-01     200 2022-01-01
6    Zoya S 2022-08-01     181 2022-01-01
7    Zoya S 2022-09-01     177 2022-01-01
8    Zoya S 2022-10-01     207 2022-01-01
9    Zoya S 2022-11-01     323 2022-01-01
10   Zoya S 2022-12-01     210 2022-01-01
11   Zoya S 2023-01-01     361 2022-01-01
12   Zoya S 2023-02-01     490 2022-01-01
13   Zoya S 2023-03-01     415 2022-01-01
14   Zoya S 2023-04-01     773 2022-01-01
15   Zoya S 2023-05-01     372 2022-01-01
16   Zoya S 2023-06-01     275 2022-01-01
17   Zoya S 2023-07-01     322 2022-01-01
18   Zoya S 2023-08-01     391 2022-01-01
19   Zoya S 2023-09-01     335 2022-01-01
20   Zoya S 2023-10-01     294 2022-01-01
21   Zoya S 2023-11-01     253 2022-01-01
22   Zoya S 2023-12-01     269 2022-01-01
23   Zoya S 2024-01-01     278 2022-01-01
```

`Zoya S` begins work from `2022-06-01`  , so i need extrapolate data based on its history from (2022-06-01 - 2024-02-01)​​from 2022-06-01 to 2022-01-01(in past). That is, we predict in the back direction. And so for each `id_manag`. From the date when it appeared only, for example  For `Alek P` from 2022-08-01 to 2022-01-01 based on his data by `seconds` from 2022-08-01 to 2024-02-01

Desired output would for Zoya example

```
id_manag    month   seconds
**Zoya  01.01.2022  300
Zoya    01.02.2022  326
Zoya    01.03.2022  350
Zoya    01.04.2022  323
Zoya    01.05.2022  303**
Zoya    01.06.2022  117
Zoya    01.07.2022  200
Zoya    01.08.2022  181
Zoya    01.09.2022  177
Zoya    01.10.2022  207
Zoya    01.11.2022  323
Zoya    01.12.2022  210
Zoya    01.01.2023  361
Zoya    01.02.2023  490
Zoya    01.03.2023  415
Zoya    01.04.2023  773
Zoya    01.05.2023  372
Zoya    01.06.2023  275
Zoya    01.07.2023  322
Zoya    01.08.2023  391
Zoya    01.09.2023  335
Zoya    01.10.2023  294
Zoya    01.11.2023  253
Zoya    01.12.2023  269
Zoya    01.01.2024  278
```

What's the best way to do this in R?
Thank you help.

Comment: Extrapolation is always risky, but have you looked at `Hmisc::approxExtrap`?

Comment: @r2evans, no , didn't use. But thanks ,i 'll try.